# Как заместить слово в расширении файла на несколько слов

Tags: windows, windows-10, python-3.6

У меня есть `n` каталогов, в каждом из них по файлов одного формата

```
word1.word2.word3.wor4.word5.wav
```

В каждом каталоге разное количество файлов.

Нужно одновременно во всех файлах во всех каталогах заменить `word4` на 2 новых значения `word4.word.5`, таким образом, что `word5` из исходного названия занимает позицию `word6`.

Как это с помощью маски сделать?

**Пример**

```
|             Было             |                  Стало                  |
|------------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
| 110.pop.G.user1.BASS 10.wav  | 110.pop.G.user2.order-1530.BASS 10.wav  |
| 110.pop.G.user1.DRUMS 10.wav | 110.pop.G.user2.order-1530.DRUMS 10.wav |
```

Comment: А что делать с "word6", если такое имеется?

Comment: Покажите пример - 2-3 имени файлов исходные и конечные. Но вообще задача похожа на тупой string.replace.

Comment: 110.pop.G.user1.BASS 10.wav - исходник
110.pop.G.user2.order-1530.BASS 10.wav - то что нужно

110.pop.G.user1.DRUMS 10.wav - исходник
110.pop.G.user2.order-1530.DRUMS 10.wav - то что нужно

цифру в ордере тоже нужно будет менять время от времени, задавать свою

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то? Вооружайтесь модулями `pathlib` и `re` и в бой! Их вам должно быть достаточно для решения такой задачи

Comment: проблемка в том, что я не умею кодить полноценно

Comment: @FreddySwizz А вы попробуйте. Тут не требуется каких-то суперзнаний, просто запрограммировать в лоб пошагово